# href= javascript: jquery not working in FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, anchor

I have an anchor that triggers a javascript which uses jquery:

```
<a href="javascript: $('#dash-main').load('billing.php')">text</a>
```

This anchor works fine in Chrome, and even in IE, but when I use it in FF, the browsers redirects to "http://javascript: $('#dash-main').load('billing.php')".

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Consider connecting this to a function instead that calls it.

Comment: Remember to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11809922/144665) and answer to get that [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11809922/144665) rate up.

Comment: Can you link to an example?  This is quite odd and unexpected behavior.

Comment: Don't use `javascript:` HREFs. Use the cross-browser `onclick` event.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use onclick and avoid the problem:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#dash-main').load('billing.php');return false;">text</a>
```

Comment: `href="javascript:` is really ugly in the status bar. Make sure you `return false;` in the `onclick` or the page will jump.

Comment: Use `href="javascript:void(0);"` instead of `href="#"` - this avoids needing to return false at the end of `onclick`. `void(0)` is basically a no-op for javascript. In the href attribute, it keeps it from jumping to the top of the page or navigating away, regardless of what `onclick` does or does not return.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#dash-main').load('billing.php')">text</a>
```

Cross-browser compatible!

Answer (score -3):

Did you try returning false?

```
<a href="javascript: $('#dash-main').load('billing.php'); return false;">text</a>
```

Comment: What about just putting an ";" at the end of your statement?